# Regex look ahead/behind with word boundary

Tags: regex

First I have a regex `cat(?=mouse\b)` it matches against `cat` in a `catmouse x`. But I want a version where there is a word boundary between `cat` and the `mouse`. So I tried these regex

- `cat(?=\bmouse\b)`
- `cat\b(?=mouse\b)`

But none of the above match `cat` in a `cat mouse x`. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: There is no space in the pattern. Perhaps like `cat(?= ?mouse\b)` using an optional space https://regex101.com/r/T3Y89J/1

Comment: I have clarified the question. Maybe `cat(?=\smouse\b)` ?. But `\s` doesn't count `,` `.` characters.

Comment: Do you also want to match `cat.mouse`. or `cat,mouse`? Try `cat(?=[\s.,]?mouse\b)` https://regex101.com/r/fh9xsA/1

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Why does `cat(?=\bmouse\b)` not work for `cat mouse` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an optional space in the lookahead as there is no [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) between `catmouse`

```
cat(?= ?mouse\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T3Y89J/1)

To match either a dot, comma or a space and not match `catmouse` you could use a character class:

`cat(?=[\s.,]mouse\b)`

**Explanation**

- `cat` Match literall
- `(?=` Postive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `[\s.,]` Match either a whitespace char, dot or comma
  - `mouse\b` Match `mouse` and a word boundary
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBNbKO/1)

If you don't want cat to be part of a larger word, you might prepend a word boundary `\bcat`

---

Per the `www.regular-expressions.info` linked documentation, there are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: With the second version I don't want to match `catmouse`

Comment: You could make the character class non optional `cat(?=[\s.,]mouse\b)` https://regex101.com/r/oBNbKO/1

Comment: What's the difference between `[\s,.]` and the `\b`?

Comment: Seems like `\bcat\b` and `(?<=[\s.,])cat(?=[\s.,])` are same.

Comment: `[\s,.]` is a character class which will match either a whitespace char, comma or a dot. The `\b` is a word boundary which is an anchor, matches a position and the match is zero length. Using `(?<=[\s.,])cat(?=[\s.,])` is a different concept called lookarounds, which are also zero length.

Comment: Yeah but it seems to be doing the same thing, I'm not wondering about what they are called but the result.

Comment: They are not the same, but using it with the previous data it got the same result because `\s` also matches a newline which was there. If you take a look at this example, you see that it is not the same https://regex101.com/r/V4HEyE/1 If you use the second version from the answer you see the difference in matches https://regex101.com/r/MHDfDN/1

Answer (score 1):

Oh you are so close :)
I think you didn't fully understand the word boundary `\b`.

#### How \b works in regex

At the beginning of a string it will make sure your word does start with the characters which come after. `\bmouse` will match every word starting with mouse.

```
Regex: '/\bmouse/'
Matches: Mouse, MouseMouse, MouseCat, Mouse...
Fails: CatMouse, MyMouse, EtcMouse
```

If `\b` is put after a string, this makes sure it does not continue the word.

```
Regex: '/mouse\b/'
Matches: Mouse, MouseMouse, CatMouse, ...Mouse
Fails: MouseCat, MouseHouse, MouseEtc
```

Putting both together makes sure you have an enclosed word

```
Regex: '/\bmouse\b/'
Matches: Mouse
Fails: NoMouse, MouseNo, NoMouseNo
```

#### Results

The `\b` basically tells you about the combined word only. If you want something extra you need to mention that. The regex you want is probably this:

```
cat(?=[.,\ ]mouse\b)
```

*Note: The first `\b` was replaced by the characters you wanted to filter.*

Comment: I should have tried `cat\bmouse` alone. It doesn't work for `cat mouse`

Comment: Maybe because `\b` doesn't consume anything

Comment: Well `cat\bmouse` asks for a word stop inside catMouse which would break the word. \b inside a word does not make sense. It would need to be 'catMouse' and 'cat Mouse' at the same time => always false

Comment: Yeah turns out it wasn't even a look problem. `cat\bmouse` statement itself is absurd